# A theorem on matrix algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Definition : Let $ E_{ij}$ denote the 2*2 matrix whose (i,j) entry is 1, all other entries are zero.

Theorem: If a 2*2 matrix A commutes with $E_{ij}$ (in other words $ AE_{ij}=E_{ij}A $ ), then $A_{ii} = A_{jj}$ and all other entries of its i'th columns and all other entries of its j'th rows are zero.

How do we prove this theorem ?

Where do i start?
What does it exactly mean by saying $A_{ii} = A_{jj}$
 Does it mean that A should be a diagonal matrix?
If so , how can i start a rigorous proof? Would entry-wise approach be helpful?

Comment: $A_{ij}$ here is the entry of $A$ in row $i$ and column $j$. You start by taking an arbitrary matrix $A$ and prove the statement by writing down what $AE_{ij} = E_{ij}A$ means.

Comment: So, $A_{ii} $ is one of the main diagonal entry . Then what is $A_{jj}$ . is it another diagonal entry. does that mean all diagonal entries are equal?

Comment: **Hint:** 
$$
AE_{ij} = A e_ie_j^T = (A e_i)e_j^T\\
E_{ij}A = e_i e_j^TA = e_i(e_j^T A)
$$

Comment: what is $ e_i ? $

Comment: You might start by verifying this in the $2\times 2$ and $3\times 3$ case, so you can see what the theorem is saying.  Extrapolate from there.

Comment: bigboss only considers 2x2 matrices, as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes that is true. But you re not helping out